# IE6 closes new browser window when I set iframe's source to a file download service

Tags: file, download, internet-explorer-6

In our application, we have a download flow that works as follows:

1. On main application page has a link showing file name to download. Target of this link is _blank.
2. User clicks this link. We open a new window.
3. The new window shows a wait message, makes an ajax call first to verify the file details from server (we have server implementations for this).
4. There is a hidden iframe in new window. After verification of file details, I set the file download url as the source of iframe so download request is sent via iframe.
5. When file response is received, IE6 suddenly shows a yellow bar at the top and then closes this new window forcefully. I do not see any file save dialog.

This works fine in IE7 and IE8, although I see the yellow security bar here too but window does not close, so I can start a manual download.

Can anyone help me on this? Is this a bug in IE6 that was resolved in IE 7/8?

Best regards,
Nadeem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. Actually this is a bug of IE6 and you could get more info about it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/896017.

Regards,
Nadeem Ullah

Comment: Microsoft has given another patch if issue persists after applying the above patch, you could get it here: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/928540